# While loop stops despite conditions being true

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm merging 2 sorted linked list into one sorted list. My code gets everything except for the last output.

```
   class Solution {
    private:
        ListNode* head = NULL;
        ListNode* current1 = NULL;
        ListNode* current2 = NULL;
        ListNode* current3 = NULL;

    public:
        ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

            setPointers(l1,l2); //  set current pointers to beginning of each list

            while((current1) && (current2)) {

                if((current1->val <= current2->val) || (current2 == NULL)) {  
                    ListNode* newNode = new ListNode;
                    newNode->val = current1->val;
                    current1 = current1->next; 

                    if(isEmpty(head)) {
                        head = newNode;
                        current3 = newNode;
                    }
                    else {
                        current3->next = newNode;
                        current3 = current3->next;
                    }
                }

                else if((current2->val <= current1->val) || (current1 == NULL)) {
                    ListNode* newNode = new ListNode;
                    newNode->val = current2->val;
                    current2 = current2->next; 

                    if(isEmpty(head)) {
                        head = newNode;
                        current3 = newNode;
                    }
                    else {
                        current3->next = newNode;
                        current3 = current3->next;
                    }
                }
            }
            return head;
        }

        bool isEmpty(ListNode* head) {
            if(head == NULL) 
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        void setPointers(ListNode* list1, ListNode* list2) {
            current1 = list1;
            current2 = list2;
        }
    };`
```

> Your input [1,2,4] [1,3,4]  Output [1,1,2,3,4]  Expected [1,1,2,3,4,4]

I thought the while loop keeps going until both current1 and current2 are both NULL but it seems to stop before making the last comparison.

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Answer (score 4):

The `&&` operator evaluates to true only if *both* operands are true (i.e. not null in your case). Once at least one of the operands is false, then the loop stops.

You probably wanted `while (current1 || current2)`, which will loop while at least one operand is not null.

edit:
also, be careful on the order of evaluation:

```
if((current1->val <= current2->val) || (current2 == NULL))
```

you are accessing `current2` before checking whether it is not null (&& and || conditions are evaluated from the left, short-circuiting when the result is obvious from the value of the first operand).

You cannot be sure that `current1` in the above condition is not null either.

Comment: Thanks the while loop makes sense now! However, I switched the ordering of the current2 == NULL and current1 == NULL in the if statements but getting a runtime error. Saying undefinedBehaviorSanitizer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but rather a comment, which I can't fit into the comments section. Why is your code so complicated? Merging two list is a very simple operation - and so should be your code:

```
Node* merge(Node* list1, Node* list2) {
    Node* head = nullptr;
    auto tail = &head;

    while (list1 && list2) {
        auto& list = (list2->value < list1->value) ? list2 : list1;
        *tail = std::exchange(list, list->next);
        tail  = &(*tail)->next;
    }

    if (list1)
        *tail = list1;
    else if (list2)
        *tail = list2;

    return head;
}
```

The simpler your code is, the less is the chance to make an error.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QZmLWb)